# PHP не показывает дату

Tags: php, дата

Пишу:

```
date("d-m-y");
```

показывает год 2003!

Пишу:

```
date("y-m-d");
```

Показывает все верно! Но не в том порядке, в котором я хочу.

Пишу:

```
date("d-m-Y");
```

Показывает 0000-00-00!

Что тут происходит? В чем проблема такого глюка???

Comment: Попробуйте с одинарными кавычками - мало ли, строки как-то эвальюируются у вас. Хотя не должны. [Пример](http://ideone.com/22A3UH) работает без косяков.

Comment: то же самое

Comment: Hashcode уже не тот. Никто уже не помогает.

Comment: У вас чистый php файл с единственной строчкой этой с датой, или это посреди огромного фреймворка с кучей плагиинов?  

Разместите эти строки в отдельном php файле, и приведите вывод `phpinfo()`.

Comment: > Hashcode уже не тот. Никто уже не помогает.

Ну как бэ вам уважаемый с момента даты вашей регистрации на ХК давно пора было изучить php и помогать!

Comment: > Hashcode уже не тот. Никто уже не помогает.

Послал гигансткий лучеминус в карму

Answer (score 4):

> Пишу:
>
> date("d-m-y"); показывает год 2003!

Так что ли? 03-07-14
И с чего вдруг у Вас тут год 2003? Если первым идёт день.

Ну а если уж совсем паранойя то передавайте вторым параметром time()

```
date("d-m-Y", time())
```